# NGRX - Is correct to reset the state assigning reducer initial state?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx

I have an ngrx-state defined in this way:

```
initialSidebarState: {
  companyList: [];
  companyId: null;
```

}

I'm working with an ngrx, I have an action called "changeCompany":
createAction('[Sidebar] Change Company', props<{ companyId: number }>());

and  I have a reducer function defined in this way:

```
on(
SidebarAction.changeCOmpany,
(state, action): SidebarState => {
  return {
    ...state,
    companyList: initialSidebarState.companyList,
    companyId: action.companyId
  };
}
```

),

I restored the company list assigning the initialSidebarState.companyList property, is this correct or not?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. But I would maybe suggest having a `const` which has a default value of `companyList` if this list is not empty by default. If it's empty by default, just assign an empty array in reducer.

```
const DEFAULT_COMPANY_LIST = [company, company, ...]

initialSidebarState: {
  companyList: DEFAULT_COMPANY_LIST;
  companyId: null;
}

on(
  SidebarAction.changeCOmpany,
  (state, { companyId }): SidebarState => ({
    ...state,
    companyList: DEFAULT_COMPANY_LIST, // If you just want to clear it => companyList: []
    companyId
  })
),
```